# Уходить в ретрит? на ретрит?

Tags: предлоги

> Ретри́т, (англ. retreat [ɹɪˈtɹiːt] — «уединение», «удаление от
>   общества», рус. лит. «затвор») — английское слово, вошедшее в русский
>   язык как международное обозначение времяпрепровождения, посвящённого
>   духовной практике.

У меня:

> На деле этот орден держит очень суровую аскезу. Особое внимание
>   уделяет дисциплине, уединению и размышлению. И нередко храм Четырёх
>   увенчанных мучеников закрыт. Вот, например, с 30 июля они вообще
>   **уходят на месяц в «ретирит»** – так гласит объявление при входе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: ***уйти в ретрит*** — перейти/прийти в состояние, предлог В.

Пример:

Что такое ретрит. Основные причины ухода в ретрит.

Источник: https://bestlavka.ru/chto-takoe-retrit/